# Pasar un #define como puntero en una función

Tags: c

Partiendo de la declaración de la siguiente función genérica para escribir datos en una memoria:

```
    void mem_write(uint16_t memory_addr, uint8_t *p_data, uint16_t length_data)
    {
         ...
    }
```

Y sabiendo de antemano qué quiero escribir y dónde:

```
    #define MEMORY_ADDR          0x0500
    #define VALOR_DATA           50
    #define LENGTH_VALOR_DATA    1
```

¿Qué posibilidades (consideradas como buenas prácticas de programación) se os ocurren a la hora de pasar el valor de VALOR_DATA como parámetro de función teniendo en cuenta que la función espera un puntero?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos,

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Qué posibilidades (consideradas como buenas prácticas de programación) se os ocurren a la hora de pasar el valor de VALOR_DATA como parámetro de función teniendo en cuenta que la función espera un puntero?

Para empezar, si `VALOR_DATA` es una macro, ésta será global y no necesitarás pasarla a la función: ¡ya está presente en la función!

```
#define MEMORY_ADDR          0x0500
#define VALOR_DATA           50
#define LENGTH_VALOR_DATA    1

void mem_write(void)
{
     // … MEMORY_ADDR es visible aquí
     // … VALOR_DATA es visible aquí
     // … LENGTH_VALOR_DATA es visible aquí
}
```

Para acabar, si te preocupan las buenas prácticas de programación, olvida las macros (`#define`), hace décadas que no se consideran buena práctica por los siguientes motivos:

- No son un constructo del lenguaje si no un mecanismo ajeno al mismo.
- Son globales sin contexto ni tipo.
- Pueden causar conflictos de nombres difíciles de detectar.

Mi consejo es que uses una estructura:

```
typedef struct {
    int MEMORY_ADDR;
    int VALOR_DATA;
    int LENGTH_VALOR_DATA;
} data;

void mem_write(data d) { /* … */ }

int main(void)
{
    data d;
    d.MEMORY_ADDR = 0x0500;
    d.VALOR_DATA = 50;
    d.LENGTH_VALOR_DATA = 1;

    mem_write(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes reemplazar los `#define` por **variables constantes**:

```
const uint16_t MEMORY_ADDR = 0x5000;
const uint8_t VALOR_DATA = 50;
const uint16_t LENGTH_VALOR_DATA = 1;
```

Las ventajas de `const` sobre `#define` son varias:

- Tipado fuerte: Si tienes un conflicto de tipos el compilador se quejará
- No son macros, luego no provocarán reemplazos inesperados

> ¿Qué posibilidades (consideradas como buenas prácticas de programación) se os ocurren a la hora de pasar el valor de VALOR_DATA como parámetro de función teniendo en cuenta que la función espera un puntero?

Para eso puedes usar el operador `&`:

```
mem_write(MEMORY_ADDR, &VALOR_DATA, LENGTH_VALOR_DATA);
//                     ^ obtenemos la dirección de VALOR_DATA
```

Ahora bien, dado que las variables `constexpr` son constantes, la llamada anterior no compilará y tiene su parte de razón. El puntero **debe ser constante**, ya que de otra forma se daría a entender que la función `mem_write` va a modificar el contenido del puntero cuando no debe ser así:

```
void mem_write(uint16_t memory_addr, uint8_t const* p_data, uint16_t length_data)
```